# Extra Ajax on CGridView on Yii

Tags: php, ajax, yii, cgridview

I'm quite new with Yii and I'm dealing with the `CGridView` which is causing me troubles.

This `CGridView` is in a `renderPartial` view.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'ratesGrid',
'dataProvider'=>rates::model()->searchSameProperty($propertyid),
'columns'=>array(
    'name',
    'from',
    'to',
    'price',
    array( 
    'header'=>'html',
    'type'=>'raw',
    'value'=>'\'
       <a href="#" class="deleteRate btn btn-danger" data-rateid="\'.$data->id.\'">Delete Rate</a>
       \'', 
    ),
),));

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('ratesdeletion', '
$("#ratesProperty").on("click", ".deleteRate", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        "url":"'.CController::createUrl('rates/delete').'",

            "type":"POST",
            "data":{
                "id":$(this).data("rateid"),
            },
            "success":function(data){
                $.fn.yiiGridView.update("ratesGrid");
            },

    });
});
', CClientScript::POS_END);
```

The good part is when I click the delete button, it makes the call to "rates/delete" with the correct id, but when "rates/delete" finishes its work, somehow another AJAX call is made (that I've never coded), please check the screenshot.

[image: Network tab on WebDev Tools]

So my questions are:

1. Why Yii is creating this second ajax call that I've never created?
2. How can I avoid this second ajax call?

EDIT:

I tried adding an anchor and then attach the ajax call in a click event and it keeps making the second call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete some items from a grid, first ajax call is for delete request to server and second request is for recreating the grid after your deletion. We can't avoid second ajax call while using ajax grid view like this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer, so I should change it to a custom button?